# How to maintain the count of db records in print preview in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, print-preview

I am developing an appplication in which i Have 46 records and I am intended to displays 15 records on each page in print preview. but its showing 14 on first page and 15 on both page 2 & 3 and last record on page 4. Thats good. Issue is with page 1. why? Here is the code I have tried. I am using SQL and C#.

```
private void printDocument1_BeginPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        { 
          //lets suppose i populated the data table and then add a new column "PageNo"  
            dt.Columns.Add("PageNo");
            dt.AcceptChanges();
            //dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            int cPage = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i % 15 == 0)

                    cPage++;

                    dt.Rows[i - 1]["PageNo"] = cPage;                 

            }

                dt.AcceptChanges();

            CURRENT_PAGE = 0;
            if (dt.Rows.Count <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No records found!");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        SWITCH_PAGE = false; //variable to switch to next page

        DataRow[] curPageRows = { };
        curPageRows = dt.Select("PageNo=" + CURRENT_PAGE);

        int ri = 0;
        // while (totalnumber < maxRows)
        for (ri = 0; ri < curPageRows.Length; ri++)
        {
            e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Document;
            printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("Custom", 850, 1340);

            e.Graphics.DrawString(curPageRows[ri]["RollNo"].ToString().Trim(), new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 8), Brushes.Black, 700, (220 * ri) + 490);

            if (ri <= curPageRows.Length) SWITCH_PAGE = true;

        }

        if (SWITCH_PAGE == true)
        {
            CURRENT_PAGE++;
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bdf.Draw(sheetNo.ToString(), 30), 1750, 150);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(sheetNo.ToString(), new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 8), Brushes.Black, 1750, 240);
            sheetNo++;
            e.HasMorePages = true;


        }
        else
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bdf.Draw(sheetNo.ToString(), 30), 1750, 150);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(sheetNo.ToString(), new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 8), Brushes.Black, 1750, 240);
            SWITCH_PAGE = false;
            e.HasMorePages = false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: The problem is with your iteration, start from 0 and remove the subtraction from your index `dt.Rows[i - 1]`

Answer (score 0):

You should start your for-loop from 0. Here is complete for-loop for first method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (i % 15 == 0)
        cPage++;
    dt.Rows[i]["PageNo"] = cPage;                 
}
```

Comment: You are right but i can't do this as this will give me an error "THere is no row at -1"

Comment: Yeah, error might come with following clause: dt.Rows[i - 1] which gives invalid index in first round.

Comment: What should I do now?

Comment: Now its skipping first record and giving 2-15 records

Comment: After that loop, what is contents of your dt.Rows - data structure?

Comment: there are 4 items in our data i) unique id liek 1,2,3 ii)photo iii)barcode iv)barcode label

Comment: When inspecting data with dt.Rows[0]- dt.Rows[45] are those ["PageNo"]  - values correct?

Comment: no. actually it generates an extra page with no record. and by ising this code: int cPage = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if ((i-1) % 15 == 0)
                        
                    
                        cPage++;

                        dt.Rows[i]["PageNo"] = cPage;                 

                } 
only first record shows on first page and 2-16 on next page and 15 on rest of the pages

Comment: Problem is later part of code, not in this loop anymore. I tested loop logic, and cPage values was correct in my test run.

Comment: why are you still using `if ((i-1) % 15 == 0)` you have to change to `if (i% 15 == 0)`

Comment: @JesusPocoata iT GIVES ME ERROR "THERE IS no row at position -1

Comment: your index starts at 0, so according to your code, errors are not possible in that block (I mean the loop).

Comment: What is value of CURRENT_PAGE variable in start? Is there any other code touching dt-variable? I can’t imagine any case when paging can fail when using that my algorithm.

Comment: @RistoM the initiall value of Current_page is 0

Comment: I do not get the idea of following line in your second method: if (ri <= curPageRows.Length) SWITCH_PAGE = true; It seems, that SWITCH_PAGE is set to true every time in the first round of the loop. There also might be some other logic outside your pasted code which causes bug.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes because of the line

```
if (i % 15 == 0)
```

The issue is that you're starting your loop at 1 and the first question falls on page 0 which isn't visible.

What you should do is either change this to be:

```
if ( ( i - 1)  % 15 == 0)
```

or you can start your loop at 0 by doing:

```
   int cPage = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i % 15 == 0)
            cPage++;
        dt.Rows[i]["PageNo"] = cPage;                 

    }
```

Comment: No, it gives me an error " There is no row at position 46"

Comment: it was because I failed to remove an equals sign in the loop.  I have updated the code.

Comment: Thanks. But now only first record is showing on first page and 2-16 on 2nd page

Comment: This code is correct you must have another section of code that is doing a loop and there's an error there.